# sort database query with more than one value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have the following line of code to query the database, which has the value "ntd" to sort in date order.

```
public Cursor fetchAllReminders( String maybe) {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            NAME, START_DATE_TIME, NEXT_DATE_TIME, BILL_AMOUNT, OCC_AMOUNT, REF, NEXT_DATE_TIME_ACT, SUM_OCC, OCC_PERIOD, BIL_ACT, DATE_ACT, COUNTABLE, LAST, DDEBIT, ONE_OFF,ONE_OFF2 }, REF +"=?", new String[] { maybe }, null, null, "ntd", null);
}
```

Am I able to add another value so it first sorts by a boolean value then by the date value?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Android Developers Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) the `orderBy` parameter to the `SQLiteDatabase.query(...)` method is described as follows:

> How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding
>   the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default sort order,
>   which may be unordered.

this implies that you can use any valid SQL ORDER BY clause, so you should be able to pass a comma delimitted list of the columns or expressions you wish to sort by, like this:

```
"some_boolean_column, ntd"
```

Comment: You can even tweak sorting order: some_boolean_stuff asc,  ntd desc